# Using custom fields in search form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building custom search using **Advanced Custom Fields**. I used `select` field in my custom search named `'city'`, and also I am using standard category taxonomy. I find difficulties in combining this two to work together.

I think that the custom fields is not working as expected or not working at all, because when I try to search using only category its working well.

Here is my `var_dump`:

```
array (size=4)
  'relation' => string 'OR' (length=2)
  'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
  'tax_query' => 
    array (size=4)
      'taxonomy' => string 'category' (length=8)
      'field' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'terms' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 147
      'operator' => string 'IN' (length=2)
  'meta_query' => 
    array (size=2)
      'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'key' => string 'city' (length=8)
          'value' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'New York'
          'type' => string 'CHAR' (length=6)
          'compare' => string '=' (length=1)
```

Any directions for my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard taxonomy needs to be set on `tax_query` and the custom field(created by Advanced Custom Field plugin) needs to be set on `meta_query`. Also in my case I needed to set multiple values for custom field and that can be achieved by creating multiple arrays.

Here is the working example:

```
$taxquery['tax_query'] = array(
                                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                'field'  => 'id',
                                'terms'  => $categories,
                                'operator'=> 'IN'
                            );

$query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);

$filter = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                      'key' => 'location',
                      'value' => 'New York',
                      'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                       'key' => 'location',
                       'value' => 'Chicago',
                       'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
               );

$query->set('meta_query',$filter);
```